# During writing into text file splitting into a new file after Nth Rows in java?

Tags: java, filewriter

Suppose I have **105 records** and I want write all records in text files where in each file there will be **10 records**.

so total file will generate here 11.

Comment: Do you have some code? Just use a for-loop. For example `int maxCnt = 10;    for(int i=0;i<maxCnt;i++){ //Write records in file#i }`
Do you have to do it with 'FileWriter' ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? In which way was the result of your attempts different from the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

    int count = 0; String filename = "text1";
    for (int i = 0; i <= 105; i++) // loop to 105 times
    {
       count++;
       if(count <= 10) //write 10 records to the file
       {
            if(count == 1)
                filename = "text" + (i/10); 

            try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename, true)))) {
            out.println("the text");

            }catch (IOException e) {}
            if(count == 10)
                count = 0;
       }
    }
```

Comment: ...but please don't hardcode the limits. In any "real" code (no matter whether production or homework), this should be in a method, the input (some kind of collection, probably a List) and the number of entries per file should be parameters (probably the filename-pattern too).

Comment: @Harshit , in file writing position i am written below code but it's creates only one file.
File file = new File(filename+".txt");
      // creates the file
      file.createNewFile();
      // creates a FileWriter Object
      FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file); 
      writer.write("avijit");   // Writes the content to the file
      writer.flush();
      writer.close();

Comment: @Harshit, Now it's creating 11 file but in each file there is only one record.

Comment: Actually I dont have java installed on the system, So cannot run it. So just guessing the output. Are you really appending the file or just overwriting the previous file ?

Comment: @Harshit, Every time i am creating new file.and then write into this file.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void writeToMultipleFiles(int numberOfLines, String prefix, List<String> records){
    lineCounter = 1;
    counter = 1;
    String filename = prefix + counter; 
    for (String line : records){
        if(lineCounter = numberOfLines){
            lineCounter = 1;
            counter++;
            filename = prefix + counter;
        }
        try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename, true)))) {
            out.println(line);
            lineCounter++;
        }catch (IOException e) {}

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void writeToMultipleFilesExp() {
        int lineNumber = 0;
        int rowLimit = 10;
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
        String filename = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 105; i++) {
            lineNumber++;
            try {
                if (lineNumber <= rowLimit) {
                    if (lineNumber == 1) {
                        filename = "C:\\temp\\sep\\file_" + timeStamp + "_" + + (i / rowLimit) + ".txt";
                        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename, true)));
                    } 
                    out.println("the text");                    
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (lineNumber == rowLimit || i==105) { // i==105 is needed or else last page will not be rendered.
                    lineNumber = 0;
                    out.close();
                }               
            }           
        }
    }
```